# setting php_flag error_reporting not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling, php-ini

I have always found error_reporting frustrating, I need to set the following in a .htaccess file:

```
php_flag error_reporting 22519
```

for some legacy code.

and while I'm obviously in the right place (phpinfo() says the value has been changed), the value is changed to 0!!

I can't even change it in php.ini - the value shows in phpinfo() as 22527.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I tried:

```
php_flag error_reporting 1
```

just for grins - that works.  I tried other values, and they all revert to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its "php_value", not php_flag.

Heres a comprehensive reference on PHP error reporting values that will hopefully help demystify it a little for you: http://www.bx.com.au/tools/ultimate-php-error-reporting-wizard

Comment: Thanks! Made it myself :)